# aws lambda - failed to find libmagic

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using in my lambda function the magic library to determine the file`s type. 
I first deployed it to a local container to check that everything works.

My DockerFile :

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.8
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -p .aws
COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY credentials /app/.aws/
RUN mv /app/.aws/ ~/.aws/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir  -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir  -r requirements.txt -t "/app/dependencies/"
WORKDIR /app/dependencies
RUN zip -r  lambda.zip *
```

requirements.txt :

```
python-magic
libmagic
```

In my local container when I run tests on the lambda logic everything went ok and passed (including the part that uses the magic code..).

I created a zip that contains the lambda.py code and with the python dependencies (last 3 lines in the docker file).
When I upload  the zip to aws and test the lambda I'm getting the following error :

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda': failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

As you can see, on my local container I'm using baseline image `lambci/lambda:build-python3.8` that should be the same aws uses when the lambda is launching.

I tried also to add python-magic-bin==0.4.14 to the requirements.txt instead of the magic and libmagic but it didnt help either because it seems that this module is for windows.

Into the lambda.zip I put also the lambda.py which is the file that includes my lambda function :

```
import boto3
import urllib.parse
from io import BytesIO
import magic

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    if event:
        print("Event : ", event)
        event_data = event["Records"][0]
        file_name = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event_data['s3']['object']['key'])
        print("getting file: {}".format(file_name))
        bucket_name = event_data['s3']['bucket']['name']
        file_from_s3 = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
        file_obj = BytesIO(file_from_s3['Body'].read())
        print(magic.from_buffer(file_obj.read(2048)))
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: How do you call it in your code. Its complaining about some `lambda` module, suggesting that it tries to do `import lambda` somewhere?

Comment: lambda.py is the name of my lambda file. inside my lambda file it fails to call the magic ..

Comment: Can you post relevant part of the `lambda.py` or function handler that calls it?

Comment: yeah, I added it now.

Comment: @JeyJ Have you resolved this?

Comment: @Sankalp Sharma adding a comment as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While using `filetype` as suggested by other answers is much simpler, that library does not detect as many file types as `magic` does.

You can make `python-magic` work on aws lambda with `python3.8` by doing the following:

- Add `libmagic.so.1` to a `lib` folder at the root of the lambda package. This `lib` folder will be automatically added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on aws lambda. This library can be found in `/usr/lib64/libmagic.so.1` on an amazon linux ec2 instance for example.
- Create a magic file or take the one available on an amazon linux ec2 instance in `/usr/share/misc/magic` and add it to your lambda package.
- The Magic constructor from `python-magic` takes a `magic_file` argument. Make this point to your magic file. You can then create the magic object with `magic.Magic(magic_file='path_to_your_magic_file')` and then call any function from `python-magic` you like on that object.

These steps are not necessary on the `python3.7` runtime as those libraries are already present in aws lambda.

Comment: @manatony where i can find libmagic.so.1

Comment: @soheshdoshi from here: https://amazonlinux.pkgs.org/2/amazonlinux-core-x86_64/file-libs-5.11-36.amzn2.0.1.x86_64.rpm.html -- Also, you don't need to do anything other than the first step: Add `libmagic.so.1` to the `lib` folder at the root of the lambda package.

Comment: /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc not installed on amazon linux default builds (any more?).  To install it, `sudo dnf install file-devel`

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find a way to solve this issue, therefore, I decided to use a different library called filetype .

Example how to use it :

```
   file_type = filetype.guess(file_object)
    if file_type is not None:
        file_type = file_type.MIME

    file_object.seek(0)
    print("File type : {}".format(file_type))
    if file_type == "application/gzip":
        file_binary_content = gzip.GzipFile(filename=None, mode='rb', fileobj=file_object).read()

    elif file_type == "application/zip":
        zipfile = ZipFile(file_object)
        file_binary_content = zipfile.read(zipfile.namelist()[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone finds it helpful. This is how I make my lambda become friends with `python-magic`. I used a local Ubuntu machine to create a zip-package and Python 3.7.

First, create a directory. The name doesn't matter.

```
mkdir lambda-package
cd lambda-package
```

Then, install locally python-magic. I used pip3 for it.

```
pip3 install python-magic -t .
```

Now, in your lambda-package directory create or copy (if you already have some code in your lambda) a `lambda_function.py` file. Be aware, Lambda expects such name. After this step you should have the following directory structure inside the lambda-package:

```
lambda-package
  │ lambda_function.py
  │ magic/
  │ python_magic-0.4.24.dist-info/
```

Now, zip the contents of this directory. Remember to zip the contents only, not the folder itself. So, inside the lambda-package run:

```
zip -r lambda-package.zip .
```

Final step. Create a new Lambda function from scratch. Make sure to choose a proper runtime. When your function is created, click `Upload from` -> choose `Zip file` and upload lambda-package.zip file.

Now you will be able to import python-magic normally, like this:

```
import magic
```

That's it!

p.s. The error `failed to find libmagic` appears under Python 3.8 runtime. Python 3.7 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to resolve this at the time of this writing:

1. Create a `lib/` directory in the root of your Lambda package. If you're using a Lambda layer create `opt/lib/`.
2. Download the binary package from [here](https://amazonlinux.pkgs.org/2/amazonlinux-core-x86_64/file-libs-5.11-36.amzn2.0.1.x86_64.rpm.html), it will have a filename something like `file-libs-5.11-36.amzn2.0.1.x86_64.rpm`
3. Unarchive that package. (If you're on MacOS, 7zip will work. It will extract a `.cpio` file. Extract the outputted file using the standard MacOS unarchiver)
4. Move the `libmagic.so.1.0.0` file into the `lib/` folder of your Lambda package (or `/opt/lib` directory of the Lambda layer). DO NOT move the other file in the same folder named `libmagic.so.1`, it's a symlink and not a real file and will not work.
5. Re-name `libmagic.so.1.0.0` to `libmagic.so.1`
6. Deploy